# Два класса требуют экземпляры друг друга

Tags: c#

У меня есть два класса. В каждом их них нужен экземпляр другого класса.

```
SQLite sqllite = new SQLite(config);
FireBird fb = new FireBird(config, sqllite);
```

т.е. мне нужно

```
SQLite sqllite = new SQLite(config,fb);
```

Но я так сделать не могу т.к. он еще не создан.

Местами классы менять не могу -- тоже самое получится. Что одному нужен другой, который еще не создан.

Вот у меня класс SQLite. В нем есть меод `public UserData GetData()`
Метод берет данные из SQLite и должен передать их в экземпляр `fb.InsertData(ud)`.

В свою очередь fb должен сделать тоже самое. Он должен иметь возможность взять из FireBird данные и отправить их в экземпляр `sqllite.InsertData(ud)`

Comment: код классов приведите, те фрагменты, из-за которых возникает эта зависимость

Comment: @rdorn я расширил описание, так стало понятней в чем проблема или все же код классов нужен?

Comment: понятно. перемудрили с вы классами. Вам нужно отвязать логическую модель данных от доступа к БД. Я правильно понимаю, что все это нужно для синхронизации баз FB и SQLite?

Comment: да, именно. Там по хорошему даже 3 базы данных (тупо так надо) и нужно чтобы все три имели экземпляры друг друга, чтобы данные можно было бы пересылать

Comment: Собственно VladD уже ответил, именно это вам и нужно. А вдруг заказчику будет нужно еще десяток другой синхронных БД подключить?

Answer (score 8):

То есть, вы пытаетесь связать два класса, отвечающих за разные базы данных, и скормить каждому экземпляр другого в конструкторе? Так не получится, какой-то из экземпляров вам придётся создавать первым.

Можно, конечно, было бы «пробить силой», и заинжектить нужные экземпляры после создания. Но это всё равно плохой путь: эти классы в вашей архитектуре знают слишком много друг о друге.

Я бы посоветовал делать так:

1. Классы `SQLite` и `FireBird` друг о друге не знают.
2. Логика получения данных из одного и передачи другому находится во внешнем по отношении к ним классе, который имеет ссылки на оба, и работает с ними.

Comment: Мне когда-то приятель говорил, что для этого используются IDBRepository это в ту степь?

Comment: @Suliman: Я бы сказал, что это просто бизнес-логика. Она может обращаться к базам как прямо через `SQLite` и `FireBird`, так и через repository, как вам больше нравится.

Comment: так, а как быть. Предположим я создаю интерфейс, в котором описываю методы Connect, GetData, InsertData, как быть если я создаю новый класс GetInsertData и потом реализую все эти методы там. Они же не будут привязаны к конкретной БД. 

Получается для каждой БД свои методы тогда создать проще и не морочиться с экземплярами классов? GetDataFromPG InsertDataToSQLite и тд

Comment: @Suliman ну у вас же есть список методов которые нужно реализовать, опишите их интерфейсом DBProvider. В модель данных поместите например List<DBProvider> и вызывайте интерфейсные методы в цикле для каждой БД, ну или какая там у вас логика этих вызовов. Нужно сменить движок БД - дописываете провайдер к нему и меняете, нужно добавить новый - аналогично. Кода больше, да, но и польза станет заметна раньше чем вы упретесь в невозможность добавить еще один новый костыль